# Centripetal acceleration 12

Tags: geometry

[image]
Can some explain why is <AOB = <RPQ

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: Show your try in solving the problem.

Comment: Because $v_1$, $v_2$, and $\Delta v$ are proportional to $r_1$, $r_2$, and $\Delta r$ respectively, triangles QPR and AOB are similar, and that’s why their corresponding angles are congruent.

Comment: Because both $\vec v$ are tangential to the circle, and are perpendicular to their corresponding $\vec r$.

Comment: Point your left arm to your left, then turn your body $ \ 90º \ \ . $   How many degrees and in what direction did your arm turn by?

Comment: Because $\vec{v}_i\perp\vec{r}_i$, $i=1,2$. Two pairs of perpendicular lines in plane form congruent angles.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are tangent to the circle with centre $o$, which means that the angles from $o$ to $A$ and $B$ to the respective arrow-heads are both right angles ($90^\circ$). Thus, from basic geometry, the angle between $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ is the same as the angle between $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$.